# very tricky join python/pandas - attribution modeling related

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 tables: one with purchases and timestamp and one with events and timestamp.

```
Table1: 

user_id  | purchase_revenue | time_stamp 

1  |  10.0        |      07.10.2019
1  |  20.0        |      09.10.2019 


Table2: 

user_id | event_id  | time_stamp 

1  | 1    |     05.10.2019
1  | 2    |     06.10.2019
1  | 3    |     07.10.2019
1  | 2    |     08.10.2019
1  | 3    |     09.10.2019
```

I want to join them such a way that i want collect events only relevant for that purchase.
For ex: in the above scenario. The resultant join would be:

```
Joined_table:

User_id | purchase_revenue | event_id | event_order
1       | 10               |   1      |    1
1       | 10               |   2      |    2
1       | 10               |   3      |    3
1       | 20               |   2      |    1
1       | 20               |   3      |    2
```

So events 1, 2 & 3 take credit for purchase 10.0 and events 2 and 3 take credit for purchase 20.0.

Is this doable in Python?

Comment: Where do you get the event_order from?

Comment: Looks like a `merge_asof` on `time_stamp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes we have a method `merge_asof`

```
df1.time_stamp = pd.to_datetime(df1.time_stamp,dayfirst=True)
df2.time_stamp = pd.to_datetime(df2.time_stamp,dayfirst=True)
out = pd.merge_asof(df2,df1,by='user_id',on='time_stamp',direction = 'forward')
out['event_order']=out.groupby(['user_id','purchase_revenue']).cumcount()+1

out

Out[527]: 
   user_id  event_id time_stamp  purchase_revenue  event_order
0        1         1 2019-10-05              10.0            1
1        1         2 2019-10-06              10.0            2
2        1         3 2019-10-07              10.0            3
3        1         2 2019-10-08              20.0            1
4        1         3 2019-10-09              20.0            2
```